# Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to `hibernate` and trying to understand it. I have below tables :-

We have `session_tbl` table as below :-

```
Session_ID | Creation_Time  
1          | 23-Mar-2014
2          | 24-Mar-2014
3          | 25-Mar-2014
4          | 26-Mar-2014


and stock_tbl as below :- 

Stock_id   | price   | session_id
1          | 11.00   | 1
2          | 12.00   | 1
3          | 43.00   | 1
4          | 51.00   | 2
5          | 85.00   | 4
6          | 61.00   | 3
7          | 66.00   | 2
8          | 81.00   | 1
```

in above `session_id` is using as foreign key for `session_tbl`.

In `hibernate` how can we specify mapping in `xml` file ?
I want to fetch `stock_tbl` data only, i will never query `session_tbl` to get stock.

We need `Session_tbl` object need to be created in `Stock_tbl` class. But no `Stock_tbl` object with `Session_tbl` class.

We want to use `session_tbl` for tracking purpose  we have more then 100 table which are having `session_tbl` as foreign key in all the table. in this case we have to put Set for all the classes in `Session_tbl` unnecessary. As we want session details only from `Stock_tbl` and same with all remain 99 tables (when required fetch `session_tbl` - lazy loading).

I have created mapping as below :-

```
public class Session_tbl {
   private int session_id;
   private String dateTime; 
   private Set<Stock_tbl> stockTbl;
   // Question 1 


.. Getter and Setter
}

public class Stock_tbl{
   private int stock_id;
   private Session_tbl sessionTbl;
   private int price; 

.. Getter and Setter
}

<class name="Session_tbl" table="session_tbl">

      <id name="session_id" type="int" column="session_id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <set name="stockTbl" cascade="all">
         <key column="stock_id"/>
         <one-to-many class="Stock_tbl"/>
      </set>
      // Question 2
......

</Class>

<class name="Stock_tbl" table="stock_tbl">

      <id name="stock_id" type="int" column="stock_id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      ....
   </class>
```

**Question:**

1. Why do i need to use set in Session_tbl class because i dont want to fetch stock from here? i need only Session_tbl Object in below class.
2. Why this mapping needed in Sesison_tbl table? for all the 100 classes do i have to create there mapping here?

Comment: Posting the table structure as CREATE TABLE statements will generally make it easier on people answering.

Comment: Question of personal taste. The table structure in its current format is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define only the ManyToOne part of the relationship in your Stock_tbl class.
You don't need to add anything to the Session_tbl class, or any other of your 100 classes if they don't want to use their relationsip to the Session.

```
<class name="Stock_tbl" table="stock_tbl">

      <id name="stock_id" type="int" column="stock_id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="sessionTbl" column="session_id" class="Session_tbl" not-null="true"/>
      ....
</class>
<class name="Session_tbl" table="session_tbl">

      <id name="session_id" type="int" column="session_id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      //remove the stockTbl field from the Session class
</Class>
```

With anotation (recommended instead of xml as the mappings is next to your code), it simply looks like that:

```
@Entity
public class Stock_tbl{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int stock_id;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="session_id")
   private Session_tbl sessionTbl;
   private int price; 

.. Getter and Setter
}

@Entity
public class Session_tbl {
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int session_id;
   private String dateTime; 
   //remove the stock if you dont want to use it
.. Getter and Setter
}
```

Unless you meant that you really don't want to have the Session class at all.
Then you don't provide any Session_tbl mapping.
Inside your Stock_tbl you defined just the column for session_id, and you will need to handle it yourself (ie. set the correct sessionId value).

```
@Entity
public class Stock_tbl{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private int stock_id;

   private int session_id; //now it is a simple id, not relationships/objectc
   private int price; 
.. Getter and Setter
}
```